# Merge json element from list

Tags: json, ruby, merge

I am currently looking to merge elements from a list. These elements are in a hash as below. The code is in Ruby

```
[
{
   :id => 0,
   :value => ["titi"],
   :allow => true,
   :text => "titi"
},
{
   :id => 0,
   :value => ["tata"],
   :allow => true
   :text => "tata"
}, 
{
   :id => 1,
   :value => ["blabla"],
   :allow => true,
   :text => "blabla"
}, 
{
   :id => 2,
   :value => ["ok"],
   :allow => true,
   :text => "ok"
}, 
{
   :id => 2,
   :value => ["ko"],
   :allow => true,
   :text => "ko"
}
]
```

My goal is to merge the field value based on the same "id". to get something like:

```
[
{
   :id => 0,
   :value => ["titi", "tata"],
   :allow => true,
   :text => "titi, tata"
},
{
   :id => 1,
   :value => ["blabla"],
   :allow => true
   :text => "blabla"
}, 
{
   :id => 2,
   :value => ["ok", "ko"],
   :allow => true,
   :text => "ok, ko"
}
]
```

I have tried to use list.map and parse it but it's not working.

based on the answer below, I have tried to add text field but it failed to do it nicely

Any idea ?

Comment: You say the code is in Ruby, but it's not. Can you make that a proper Ruby structure?

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Enumerable#group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by), you can groups collections by result of given block:

```
[1, 2, -1, 3, -3].group_by { |i| i.abs }
# => {1=>[1, -1], 2=>[2], 3=>[3, -3]}
[1, 2, -1, 3, -3].group_by { |i| i.abs }.values
# => [[1, -1], [2], [3, -3]]
```

By combining grouped collections, you will get what you want

```
ary = [
  { id: 0, value: ["titi"],   allow: true },
  { id: 0, value: ["tata"],   allow: true }, 
  { id: 1, value: ["blabla"], allow: true }, 
  { id: 2, value: ["ok"],     allow: true }, 
  { id: 2, value: ["ko"],     allow: true }
]

ary.group_by { |h| h[:id] }.values.map { |hs|
  hs.inject { |h1, h2|
    # h1 = h1.clone  # to preserve original hash (in ary)
    h1[:value] += h2[:value]
    h1

    # OR
    # h1.merge(h2) { |key, oldval, newval|
    #   key == :value ? oldval + newval : oldval
    # }
  }
}

# => [{:id=>0, :value=>["titi", "tata"], :allow=>true},
#     {:id=>1, :value=>["blabla"], :allow=>true},
#     {:id=>2, :value=>["ok", "ko"], :allow=>true}]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to use the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that uses a block to determine the value of keys that are present in both hashes being merged.

```
arr = [
  { id: 0, value: ["titi"],   allow: true },
  { id: 0, value: ["tata"],   allow: true }, 
  { id: 1, value: ["blabla"], allow: true }, 
  { id: 2, value: ["ok"],     allow: true }, 
  { id: 2, value: ["ko"],     allow: true }
]

arr.each_with_object({}) { |g,h|
  h.update(g[:id]=>g) { |_k,o,n| o.merge(value: o[:value]+n[:value]) } }.
    values.
    map { |g| g.merge(text: g[:value].join(', ')) }
  #=> [{:id=>0, :value=>["titi", "tata"], :allow=>true, :text=>"titi, tata"},
  #    {:id=>1, :value=>["blabla"], :allow=>true, :text=>"blabla"},
  #    {:id=>2, :value=>["ok", "ko"], :allow=>true, :text=>"ok, ko"}]
```

i
See the doc for an explanation of the block variables `_k`, `o` and `n`. The (optional) underscore in `_k` signifies that that block variable is not used in the block calculation.

Before `values` is used at the end to extract the hash values, we have computed the following:

```
arr.each_with_object({}) { |g,h|
  h.update(g[:id]=>g) { |_k,o,n| o.merge(value: o[:value]+n[:value]) } }
    #=> {0=>{:id=>0, :value=>["titi", "tata"], :allow=>true},
    #    1=>{:id=>1, :value=>["blabla"], :allow=>true},
    #    2=>{:id=>2, :value=>["ok", "ko"], :allow=>true}}
```

Comment: I would like to add a field called text which a "string" version of value.

Comment: Sep, I add the `:text` key, as you requested, but I'd advise against doing that. Rather, if `h` is the hash you construct (without a key `:text`), simply compute `text = h[:value].join(', '))` as needed. The reason is that if you include a `:text` key you need to update `h[:text]` whenever you change `h[:value]`. That's inefficient and a potential source of a nasty bug. It's just not good programming practice.